# Datastage: How to keep continuous mode job running after a unexpected termination

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, real-time, datastage, control-m

I have a job that uses the Kafka Connector Stage in order to read a Kafka queue and then load into the database. That job runs in Continuous Mode, which it has no time to conclude, since it keeps monitoring the Kafka queue in real time.
[image]

For unexpected reasons (say, server issues, job issues etc) that job may terminate with failure. In general, that happens after 300 running hours of that job. So, in order to keep the job alive I have to manually look to the job status and then to do a Reset and Run, in order to keep the job running.

The problem is that between the job termination and my manual Reset and Run can pass several hours, which is critical. So I'm looking for a way to eliminate the manual interaction and to reduce that gap by automating the job invocation.

I tried to use Control-M to daily run the job, but with no success: The first day the Control-M called the job, it ran it fine. But in the next day, when the Control-M did an attempt to instantiate the job again it failed (since it was already running). Besides, the Datastage will never tell back Control-M that a job was successfully concluded, since the job's nature won't allow that.

Said that, I would like to hear ideas from you that can light me up.

The first thing that came in mind is to create a intermediate Sequence and then schedule it in Control-M. Then, this new Sequence would call the continuous job asynchronously by using command line stage.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where just this one job terminates unexpectedly and you want it to be restarted as soon as possible, have you considered calling this job from a sequence?   The sequence could be setup to loop running this job.

Thus sequence starts job and waits for it to finish. When job finishes, the sequence will then loop and start the job again.  You could have added conditions on job exit (for example, if the job aborted, then based on that job end status, you could reset the job before re-running it.

This would not handle the condition where the DataStage engine itself was shut down (such as for maintenance or possibly an error) in which case all jobs end including your new sequence.   The same also applies for a server reboot or other situations where someone may have inadvertently stopped your sequence.   For those cases (such as DataStage engine stop) your team would need to have process in place for jobs/sequences that need to be started up following a DataStage or System outage.

For the outage scenario, you could create a monitor script (regardless of whether running the job solo or from sequence) that sleeps/loops on 5-10 minute intervals and then checks the status of your job using dsjob command, and if not running can start that job/sequence (also via dsjob command).   You can decide whether that script startup would occur at DataSTage startup, machine startup, or run it from Control M or other scheduler.